# Prove or disprove this observation: The equation: $\phi(2n+1)=n$ has no natural solution n [$\phi$ is the Euler totient function].

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In my search for properties of composite numbers that may have some prime-like behavior, I came across the question: for which $k>1$ must the relation  $\gcd(\phi(2n+1),2n/k)=1$ be always true?
For $k=2$ and $k=3$, I checked the first $10^8$ numbers for $n$ and found no $n$ satisfying the equation. The question in the title is for $k=2$, but I'll appreciate it, if anybody reacts to the case $k=3$ also.

Comment: Where is the relation to the question in the title ?

Comment: Sorry for the unfortunate formulation. Please see the comment below

Answer (score 1):

There are no such $k$.

Start with any prime $p>k$.  By Dirichlet, there are primes of the form $mp+1$, say we pick such a prime $q$.  By CRT, there exists $n$ such that $q\mid 2n+1$ and $pk\mid 2n$.  Then $\phi(q)=mp$ divides $\phi(2n+1)$, and we also have $p\mid 2n/k$, so $p\mid\gcd(\phi(2n+1),2n/k)$.

By the way, that is different from the question in title.

Comment: I am very sorry for my unfortunate formulation above. I hope I can edit it. This is my first contribution here. The question in the title is the correct one. The question is: 
For which $k$ can $2n/k$ never be a divisor of $\phi(2n+1)$ for any natural number $n$?
I checked $n<10^8$ for $k=2$ and $k=3$ and found no $n$. And this is where I am asking for proof. For $k=4$, $2n+1=65$ and $2n+1=1729$ are counterexamples for $n<1000000$. For $k=5$, counterexamples are $2n+1=21 , 91 , 3201 , 6601 , 8911 $.